# What factors help in getting a site indexed by Google fast?

Tags: google, search-engines, sitemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site’s position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

What should I do to get a site indexed on Google, fast? Taking example of [Super User](http://superuser.com) I just did a quick Google for a question that was 20 minutes old, to look for an answer, and it was already on Google Search - how is this possible?

I glanced over [this article](http://blog.kissmetrics.com/get-google-to-index/) which seems to suggest that SU has added RSS feeds (which SU has, but when I opened the feed the article says last posted 6 minutes ago, but when Googled it is 11 hours old) - which leads me to think (Based on that article, I don't know much about search indexing but I am reading at the moment) that most of this indexing is done thanks to the sitemap.

is there anything else I am unaware of that helps SU questions get on Google so fast?

Comment: Well, I am sure other websites have pretty fast indexing, I just used SU as my example because it is the only site I have noticed doing this

Comment: Google commits more indexing effort to popular and content rich sites (ie sites that have frequent new and quality content)

Comment: see also http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox

Comment: I suggest this is reopened - its asking a different question to the duplicate.

Comment: This answers how specifically stackexchange sites get indexed quickly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9726/how-does-stack-overflow-work-so-well-with-search-engines